# How to define the target (apt install -t") of a built package to distinguish when with the same name

Tags: debian, apt, cpack

I am working on a cmake project where we create a .deb package with cpack containing a C++ library. The goal is to have a pipeline running at the main branch which generates the package and places it at our local repository, same under the dev branch.

Now, to distinguish the packages that would have the same name I would like to use the `-t` option from the `apt install -t target packagename` to decide if I install the package from main that is at a local repository, for e.g., "/stable" or the package from dev that is located at the local repository "unstable".

So far I have not figured out how to achieve this.
When I have a package with the same name on different local repositories, how can I uniquely identify which one to install?

Comment: The usual solution would be for them to have different version numbers.

Comment: But the version numbers alone do not tell me if it came from stable or unstable, namely if I just do “apt install packagename” it would install the biggest version number, even if it was from the unstable rep

Comment: Indeed; you would have to understand that there are multiple versions available, and explicitly select the one you want if it's not the default. `apt-cache policy` is a good command to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, so I post here in case anyone finds it useful.

In sum:

At sources.list I added my local sources:

```
deb [trusted=yes] myrep/unstable ./
deb [trusted=yes] myrep/stable./
```

At at each repository folder I have at the beginning of the "Release" file the following:

```
Archive: unstable
Version: 1.0
Codename: unstable
Date: 2024
Architectures: amd64 i386
Components: main
Description: Unstable Local APT Repository with packages built from the dev branch
```

And the same for the "stable" repository.

Then by doing `sudo apt-get install -t unstable packagename` it installs from the unstable repository, if I do `sudo apt-get install packagename` it installs from the stable repository.